# Shouldn't the help on how to ask a good question include "make sure you ask a question"?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, help-center

One of the causes of closure of a question as unclear on our site (I'm a mod at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)) is questions that make a series of statements but fail to actually ask anything -- they leave the actual question entirely implicit. It also seems to be at least sometimes an issue on other sites I frequent.

It would be very useful if the [help/how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) pages actually included the most basic aspect of asking a question -- which is to *actually ask one*.

Could something like this small addition be made?

> Make sure you actually include your question. It may seem obvious to you what you mean to ask but it may not be so obvious to people reading your question -- it's better to be quite explicit about what you want to know.

It could perhaps go under "Be specific" for example.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly support your proposal, and would like to suggest adding an extra sentence to it.

In English (the language of almost all SE sites) a question is indicated by a question mark.

The close reason of Too Broad says "Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once".

Consequently, a simple cross-check on whether an SE question is specific can often be whether it contains a single question mark.

I propose the one sentence appended to your proposal be:

> Try to include only one question, which should be indicated
>   by a question mark, because that can be a simple cross-check on whether
>   your question is meeting the ideal of being specific.